# Intercest dataframes in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames: A and B.
A comtains two columns: Number and Letter, B also contains two columns: Number1 and Number2, and Number contains same data as in both Number1 and Number2.
How can I make a ned dataframe which will have column which contains Number1, Number2 and column with its Letter?

```
 A
Number Letter
1        e
2        l
3        o
4        s
5        p
6        w 
7        r
8        i
9        u

B
Number1 Number2
1           7
4           9
2           1
```

Needed output (without dublicats):

```
Number Letter
    1     e
    4     s
    2     l
    7     r
    9     u
```

If there was only one column in B, i would make it with "merge", but how to be here?
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [stack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) in conjunction with [isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
In [109]: A[A['Number'].isin(B.stack())]
Out[109]:
   Number Letter
0       1      e
1       2      l
3       4      s
6       7      r
8       9      u
```